# Method only called OnLoad Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple user input text and in order to avoid issues, I want to make the submit button unclickable if there is no text entered. This is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
  if ($("#formSearchUserId").val() == "") {
    $('#userIdBtn').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#userIdBtn').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

This works onload because since there is no text by default in the input, it will disable the button. However, when I type in values into the input, the button stays disabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's [`change()` event handler](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Use the `input` and/or `keyup` events too, because `change` is only triggered when you leave the field.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your code in a `$("#formSearchUserId").change(function(){ //code } )` event handler. What it does is it watches for changes in your input and triggers the function passed to whenever a change occurs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#formSearchUserId").change(function() {
  console.log($("#formSearchUserId").val())
  if ($("#formSearchUserId").val() == "") {
    $('#userIdBtn').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#userIdBtn').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=formSearchUserId name=formSearchUserId />
<button id=userIdBtn>Search</button>
```

Comment: You should chain `.change()` to the end of `.change(function() {...})` to call the handler once immediately (otherwise the button is enabled by default).

Answer (score 0):

with `keyup` :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("#formSearchUserId").val() == "") {
    $('#userIdBtn').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  $("#formSearchUserId").keyup(function() {
  console.log($("#formSearchUserId").val())
  if ($("#formSearchUserId").val() == "") {
    $('#userIdBtn').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#userIdBtn').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=formSearchUserId name=formSearchUserId />
<button id=userIdBtn>Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into `.keyup`. Just check if `value`'s availability. You can add `.trim` to avoid cases where there is just spaces.

```js
$("#formSearchUserId").on("keyup", function(){
  $('#userIdBtn').prop('disabled', !this.value.trim().length>0)
})

$(function(){
  $("#formSearchUserId").trigger("keyup");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="formSearchUserId"/>
<button id="userIdBtn">Id Btn</button>
```